# Add unused javascript file on login page

Tags: javascript, browser-cache

I have a web application where many jquery files needed after login page.
 Can i include it on the login page so that on the next page the browser don't make a request for the file.
Means the files are used from the browser cache.
 Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. That's how caching works.

Comment: will it be cached after redirect also.

Comment: yes it's a good practice preload assets that are going to likely be used. Use a cache manifest file to ensure assets caching: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can (as @Juhana already mentioned).

You can also use a [CDN](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery) like Google to deliver jQuery or other common libraries. If someone already visited another site including jQuery via Google CDN, it would be already cached by his browser when logging in to your site (if you are also using the CDN of Google).

Comment: is there any tool by which i can find whether it is  coming from the browser cache or from the server?

Comment: @krshekhar With Firefox you can list your cache entries at `about:cache`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Since you don't want to slow down login page, it is better to dynamically insert it on the page after it is loaded and rendered so user can interact with it without any delays that loading of this file might impose. Also note that this doesn't give you 100% guarantee that file will be in cache, since browser might choose not to store it or delete it before user visits your next page according to its policies and space limitations.

Answer (score 0):

You can request file anywhere with jquery `$.getScript()` method. If server caching is ON everything will be fine.